# How to locate button containing text with Selenium?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**What I need**: switch to the `Reviews` tab in description of an extension from Chrome Store (e.g. [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/emoji-keyboard-by-emojion/ipdjnhgkpapgippgcgkfcbpdpcgifncb?hl=en)) in order to count the number of reviews.

**What I've done:** Used BeautifulSoup + Selenium to switch between tabs. I used `driver.find_element_by_id('id')` **BUT** it returns an error that it can not find the element.

Here's the code I use:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    button = driver.find_element_by_id(':22')
    button.click()
    page = requests.get(driver.current_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html5lib')
    comment_list = soup.find('div', class_ = 'e-f-b-L') #the class of reviews I need to count.
```

Here's the html-code of the `Review` button element:

[image]

**Issues:**

How do I make it click the 'Reviews' button so the 'Reviews' tab is displayed?

Comment: That button doesn't do anything in terms of loading content. If you plan on using beautiful soup you can skip that part.

Comment: But the content is hidden before I push the buttom explicitly and BeautidulSoup can't find it. If it's not - I beg you to show how.

Comment: driver.find_element_by_class_name('classname').click() you can do this using class_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click on that `Reviews` tab very smoothly If you define a simple xpath like `'//div[.="Reviews"]'` or so. Check out the script as a proof of concept:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui

url = "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/emoji-keyboard-by-emojion/ipdjnhgkpapgippgcgkfcbpdpcgifncb?hl=en"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(url)
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[.="Reviews"]')).click()
driver.quit()
```

To make it headless:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui

url = "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/emoji-keyboard-by-emojion/ipdjnhgkpapgippgcgkfcbpdpcgifncb?hl=en"

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(url)
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[.="Reviews"]')).click()
print("It's done")
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for help! Does this code works for you?

Comment: Sure it is. Why it comes to your mind that there is any doubdt. Check it out yourself. Make sure to comment out this line `driver.quit()`, so that you can see the change in the browser @Sergei Shumilin.

Comment: It works!) Thank you very much!) Can you tell two more things: 1) how to handle with pagination if we don't know the exact number of pages? 2) how to make the browser open in the background in order to save the processor resourses?

Comment: For your first question: If you wanna play with pagination, create a new post describing your requirement and  drop here a link. I'll take a look. I could not understand your second question. Did you mean to run the browser headlessly?

Comment: Ok. Yes, without explicitly launch the browser

Comment: Thank you) you helped me a lot)